# Unit testing coupled methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In the example below how can I write a unit test for the Deaggregate() method, if I can't set the aggregationInfo object?

```
public class Aggregator
{
    private AggregationInfo aggregationInfo;

    public List Aggregate(List objects)
    {
        //set aggregationInfo
    }
    public List Deaggregate(List aggregatedObjects)
    {
        //use aggregationInfo for the deagregation 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't set the `aggregationInfo`object"? It must be somehow assigned inside the class, isn't it?

Comment: You could change your Aggregator class to use an `IAggregator` and an `IDeaggragotor`, then supply a `MockAggregator` when unit testing.

Comment: @tdragon I think he means `How can I test Deaggragate without also testing Aggregate at the same time?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test this by calling `Aggregate` then calling `Deaggregate`, providing different scenarios by calling aggregate with different Lists and verifying the expected behaviour in Deaggregate in those situations

Comment: why? It would test the unit `Aggregator`, which can't be used successfully without calling `Aggregate` first. Calling `Aggregate` is a setup step in the `Deaggregate` tests, in the same way that creating a mock would be. Don't get hung up in the test definitions. Verify the behaviour you want to see. That is what is important.

Comment: A 'unit' test should test one 'unit' of functionality, which may be made up of several collaborating classes. Avoid testing per class, as this leads to very brittle tests which need much work when refactoring the code. If your tests focus on units of behaviour then your tests are usually much more resilient to refactoring the code without large changes to the tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure you are unit-testing your method only, you could do the following:

```
public class Aggregator
{
    private AggregationInfo aggregationInfo;

    private readonly IAggregator aggregator;
    private readonly IDeaggragator deaggragotor;

    public Aggregator(IAggregator aggregator, IDeaggragator deaggragotor)
    {
        this.aggregator = aggregator;
        this.deaggragotor = deaggragotor;
    }

    public List Aggregate(List objects)
    {
        this.aggregationInfo = aggregator.Aggregate(objects);
        return someListIDontKnowWhereYouGetThisFrom;
    }

    public List Deaggregate(List aggregatedObjects)
    {
        return deaggregator.Deaggregate(objects, this.aggregationInfo);
    }
}
```

Your unit-test for Aggregator can then work like:

```
var systemUnderTest = new Aggregator(new MockAggregator(), new MockDeaggragator());
```

This will allow you to verify that `Aggregator` will supply the correct arguments to `IAggregator` and `IDeaggragotor`.

Finally, you can also test `RealDeaggragotor` in a separate unit-test, which is what satisfies your question.

Comment: This is a good solution, but was inapplicable for our case due to project specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your Aggregator needs to know the info, shouldn't that be the property of the returned value from Aggregate?

```
public static class Aggregator
{
    public static AggregatedList Aggregate(List objects)
    {
        // aggregate objects to aggregatedlist and set the aggregationInfo
    }

    public static List Deaggregate(AggregatedList aggregatedList)
    {
        // use info from the aggregatedList
    }
}

public class AggregatedList
{
    public AggregationInfo AggregationInfo { get; set; }
    public List AggregatedObjects { get; set; }
}
```